# Displaying multiple mysql row results in single textbox in array format separated in comma

Tags: php

Hi I have tried to select mysqli results from a table row for phone numbers but it produces many textboxes instead of only one. Please I need your help, I'll be grateful. My code is as below:

```
<form method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hrm");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))       
        {
        ?> 
        <input type='text' name='phone' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter recipients' value='<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>' />
        <?php
         }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: ``SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`phone`) AS `phone` FROM `tbl_employee`;`` will do it, although not how you expect :p

Comment: because while loop iterate as much as record in your table

Comment: Thanks, But this only displays a single phone number instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

try like this in php alone i used while inside value attr.

printing ',' will produce extra one in the last which will help to type new number

```
<form method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hrm");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);        ?> 
        <input type='text' name='phone' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter recipients'
               value='<?php
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
               echo $row['phone'].",";
               }
               ?>'
          />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks much, but this only displays a single phone number instead of all.